# check if string has .pdf extension

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to scraping. I have 2 problems. first one is that I need to scrap a particular section of the website which contains anchor tags. I need to get the anchor tags pdf links only along with their titles but unfortunately, anchor tags have normal links also.this is my first problem

the second problem is that the output having unwanted line breakups. for these 2 problems the code is the same. for same code, I have these 2 problems.

website.html

```html
<div>
<a href="www.url.com/somethin.pdf">pdf
link</a>

<a href="www.url.com/somethin.pdf">pdf
link</a>

<a href="www.url.com/somethin">normal
link</a>
</div>
```

scrappy.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.privacy.gov.ph/advisories/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

section = soup.find("section", {"class": "news_content"})
for link in section.find_all("a"):
   pdf =  link['href'].replace("..", "")
   title =  link.text.strip()
   print("title: " + title + "\t")
   print("pdf_link: " + pdf + "\t")
   print('\n')
```

If you run this code you will find the titles having unwanted new line breaks for that html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to get the href that end with the pdf extension. For the unwanted line breaks, I'm not sure what you mean. I can only assume you mean theres 2 new lines between each print. If that assumption is correct, it's because every `print` function will be on a new line. so when you have there `print('\n')`, it will print on a new line, and then print a new line. If you only want 1 space, remove that last print function and change the `\t` to `\n`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get('https://www.privacy.gov.ph/advisories/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

section = soup.find("section", {"class": "news_content"})
links = section.findAll(href=re.compile("\.pdf$")) # <---- SEE HERE

for link in links:
   pdf =  link['href'].replace("..", "")
   title =  link.text.strip().replace('\n','')
   print("title: " + title)
   print("pdf_link: " + pdf + "\n")
```

**Output:**

```
title: Updated Templates on Security Incident and Personal Data Breach Reportorial Requirements 
pdf_link: https://www.privacy.gov.ph/wp-content/files/attachments/nwsltr/Final_Advisory18-02_6.26.18.pdf        

title: Guidelines on Privacy Impact Assessments   
pdf_link: https://www.privacy.gov.ph/wp-content/files/attachments/nwsltr/NPC_AdvisoryNo.2017-03.pdf     

title: Access to Personal Data Sheets of Government Personnel 
pdf_link: https://www.privacy.gov.ph/wp-content/files/attachments/nwsltr/NPC_Advisory_No.2017-02.pdf
```

Comment: containing breaks for 2nd and 3rd title in your output.

Comment: fixed it. I wasnt sure what you meant by that

Answer (score 1):

Some titles in your case have `\n` in body - you should try this:

```
title =  link.text.strip().replace('\n', '')
```

So your final code with `.pdf` filtering will look like this:

```
section = soup.find("section", {"class": "news_content"})
for link in section.find_all("a"):
   pdf =  link['href'].replace("..", "")
   if not pdf.endswith('.pdf'):
       continue
   title =  link.text.strip().replace('\n', '')
   print("title: " + title + "\t")
   print("pdf_link: " + pdf + "\t")
   print('\n')
```